# global shortcut to start / stop video

Tags: windows-10, zoom-meeting

I can use CTRL+V shortcut to start / stop video in Zoom meetings, however it works only when Zoom is the active app.

I'd like to have a shortcut working regardless of active window. How it can be achieved?

(for microphone I have a "mute / unmute microphone" command which I can map to my programmable keys in Logi Options+, but nothing similar exists for video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make shortcuts *global* in Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts. The column on the right:

[image]